# Seeking a formula for a counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $cnt(i)$ represents the number of occurrences of $i$ in array $A$ of length $n$ whose elements are between $1$ and $n$. An array is called a $k$-good array if and only if $cnt(k)=k$ and $\forall i\not=k, cnt(i)\not=i$. Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of all $k$-good arrays of length $n$ whose elements are between $1$ and $n$.

For example, $4,2,3,3,3$ is a $k$-good array for $n=5,k=3$, but $2,2,3,3,3$ is not a $k$-good array for $n=5,k=3$, because $cnt(2)$ also equals to $2$ so you can't tell from what $k$ the array is derived.

I am wondering if there is a recursive formula for $f(n,k)$.

Comment: Interesting triangle. Where does this come from?

Comment: Does "elements are between $1$ and $n$" mean that, if $x$ is an element, then $1\lt x\lt n$? Or did you mean "between $1$ and $n$ *inclusive*"?

Comment: @bof between 1 and n inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

(Added **Update** with an inclusion-exclusion approach, see below. Also, see comment by Mike below for a fast python implementation of this.)

Some preliminary results. First some numerical values I've computed brutally for $f(n,k)$ (rows are $n\ge 1$, columns are $k\ge1$):

$$
\begin{array} 
{}f(n,k)& k=1& k=2& k=3& k=4& k=5& k=6& k=7 &k=8\\
n=1 &1 \\
n=2 &2 &  1\\
n=3 &9 &  3  & 1\\
n=4 &80 &  30&    8 &   1\\
n=5 &945  & 360 &   90  &  15    & 1\\
n=6 &13884   & 5340  &  1360  &   240   &   24  &     1\\
n=7 &242410  &  93660 &   24255  &   4480   &   525   &    35  &      1\\
n=8 & 4898872  & 1897056 &  497896 &  95270  &   12264   &   1008   &  48 &  1\\
\end{array}$$
(This triangle does not appear to be on OEIS.)
Next, we can make some observations.

Trivially $f(n,n)=1$.

For $n\ge 2$ we also have $f(n,n-1) = n(n-2)$. (We have to use exactly $n-1$ many $n-1$ in our length $n$ vector, the one extra element cannot be $1$ nor $n-1$.)

For $n\ge 5$ we have $f(n,n-2) = {n \choose 2}(n-2)^2$. (This we have to count carefully, but similar to previous by paying attention to how many 1's and 2's we used. Keep inclusion-exclusion in mind.)

Perhaps you can continue to work out the entries diagonally first, namely $f(n,n-k)$, paying attention to edges cases. Certainly a recursion or combinatorial identification of these will be more desirable.

We can also count the number of "bad" arrays, perhaps denote as $f(n,0)$, where it is not $k$-good for any $k$. Then $f(n,0) = n^n - \sum_k f(n,k)$. Some numerical values for $f(n,0)$, for $n\ge 1$, are:
$$
0 ,1 ,14, 137, 1714, 25807, 458177, 9374801,...
$$
which also does not seem to be on OEIS.

**Note.**

Perhaps a suggestion: Consdier $g(n,k)$ to be the number of of length $n$ arrays with entries from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ where there is exactly $k$ many entries with value $k$, and denote $S(n,k)$ to be this set of arrays. Then
$$
f(n,k) = |S(n,k) - \bigcup_{i\neq k} S(n,i)|,
$$
this we see clearly the inclusion-exclusion business.

---

**Update. Computing this with inclusion-exclusion**
(also, I am going to call arrays vectors, as that is more pleasing to me.)

Let $T\subset \{1,\ldots,n\}$, denote $s(n,T)$ to be the number of length $n$ vectors such that for each $t\in T$, there is exactly $t$ many $t$'s among the $n$ entries, and no restriction on the other values. Then
$$
s(n,T) = {n \choose T}(n-|T|)^{n-\sum T},
$$
where for $T=\{t_1,\ldots,t_k\}$, we write ${n\choose T} := {n \choose {t_1,\ldots,t_k}}$, multinomial coefficient; $|T|=k$ is the cardinality of $T$; and $\sum T = t_1+\cdots t_k$.

Then
$$\begin{eqnarray}
f(n,k) &=& \sum_{T\subset [n]} (-1)^{|T|+1}s(n,T) - \sum_{T\subset [n]-\{k\}} (-1)^{|T|+1}s(n,T) \\
\implies f(n,k)&=& \color{blue}{\sum_{k\in T\subset [n]} (-1)^{|T|+1}s(n,T)}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
by inclusion-exclusion. **Note:** The quantity $s(n,T)=0$ whenever $\sum T >n$, so you can prune out a lot of terms. The total number of nonzero $s(n,T)$ terms should be on the order of the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts, which I believe is on the order of $c^{\sqrt n}$ for some $c$. I didn't implement this pruning in the Octave computation below, however.

Using this and crudely implement it on Octave/Matlab I found $f(n,k)$ for:
$$
\begin{array}
{}n=9 &  112427973 &   43588944&    11564280    & 2274552    &  312102  &     29064     &   1764      &    63    &       1 \\
n=10& 2887731740 &  1120317120 &   299845680   &  60267900  &    8667288     &  878640     &   61800     &    2880   &       80   &         1\\
n=11&82060868406 &  31847443320 &   8585818065  &  1755965640    & 261829260  &    28248528    &   2198130 &       120780      &    4455 &           99   &          1\\
n=12&2555907405204   & 992122408860   & 269098056700  &   55822922100   &   8566352784 &      969619728  &      81279000     &    5005440     &     220660      &      6600   &          120      &         1
\end{array}
$$
which cost the following to compute the whole row:

```
n =  9   10.4786 seconds.
n = 10   26.563 seconds.
n = 11   60.0332 seconds.
n = 12   175.576 seconds.
```

We see this is roughly exponential $O(2^n)$ as expected. You can test out my (poorly written) Octave code at [SageMath Here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNkU1ugzAQhfc-hZczxEjxqhKIk0REailuHMIYAmbR03ds_lpUqWVhRs9v3ny2jadqtI5kJQvZ-sdoK1cbI6FBJYXkL2zofK6Ne0pb6OxR08d42z2zq0rkm6XYD4NvoQGdWUTVAK9LQk3vS2WNtAO9ElT4LeOcrzZrBK9CmJXQ-bHzI3sGIDWFpk3ZweFCMpVh-oRqKjEBShfaCfEK-y7my9gNZI5babbwI9IK9BuaYbQmJHQFt8XrYvWiMypZbLmm6ubcUDcQRWUjRjDeZ-NgP2toETSWcWzHcneCVDO8PWlMwulbuKtsPkEAck-x_ER_nJvqkONXitDi-eGKSyx_EPm_aXqW-3_TbNfSpX1-uDrQZ_WCX7PnsQg=&lang=octave&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). Pruning out the zero terms may get us to $O(c^{\sqrt n})$ by this approach.

Comment: Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to compute $f(n,k)$?

Comment: That I am not sure. Though you can reduce it to computing $O(2^n)$ many terms (inclusion-exclusion), as opposed to checking $n^n$ many arrays. And most of the terms in the inclusion-exclusion will be zero, as you cannot have a length 5 vector that is at least 2-good and at-least 4-good. (at-least $k$ good meaning $k$ shows up exactly $k$ times, no other constraints). I implemented this and it is significantly faster than brute force checking through $n^n$ many arrays. I will add my update.

Comment: Here is a [fast python program](https://tio.run/##dVNNb4MwDL3zK3xr6MdatJ0qscv@AsdJiJWwRSQOgrCtQvx2ZkOB0nY5xc7z83u2Upzdl8XnrktlBpnALeT@0QM6yelUGwjh0EeZLSEChfCdaJXGVf1RSVcxHi94PiqDnEHRnJqpNiGIXeDDeg1CSxSRDxvgGN4X6PGYWjuF1qhEc5/of6RA2MFAOdBzXNWG476glK4ucdDheWz1zoZJfik0ZMa7OEEIyf3s5KykTkH4U@LCOhQMr1lpzS03aQlm/on@koDXEHBuwnPWD@a8IKHgeupX4nDLQ9WDx7sBLhcbTIt1NzvjnOJcmeCnFNTY9at6tNU1yQd48LDfh6AWeTIxdl0upJ@aU0aCMoUtXX/3XHwglXylmWNt4tL@VJRR6ITConaCtstScSF1Qs6KXRzMTKPBfFl1Y7AouU22ykSD7RaavPWJouEfkvvtaqAZQW/WFFo6mQI1Bipg6mboR7ui9i1U8mQxrZ6odCyLrEt0L@u4QB@u0V33cvgD): 40 rows in 7 seconds!

Comment: @MikeEarnest Awesome! This motivates me to learn to use python!

Comment: and right-- we just need to sum over subsets $T$ such that $k\in T\subset [n]$. I will edit that in.

Comment: and I see, you implemented the pruning as well?

Comment: @bonsoon Indeed! [Here is some better written code](https://repl.it/@mearnest/Lists-where-k-does-not-appear-k-times#main.py). This one now works when k = 0, computing lists where no element j appears j times. I love how readable and writeable Python is!